# Add 7 days to SPField.DateTime list field

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datetime, moss, spfield

I have a SharePoint list field called ArchiveDate.

In a C# function I'm looping through the list and have the item in question.

```cs
foreach (SPListItem fListItem in fList.Items)     
{      
   foreach (SPField field in fList.Fields)      
    {
```

If `fListItem[field.Id]` has that column item with a date in it. How can I add 7 days to that date using C#?

i know I can set the value of the field to today as follows:

```
         DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; 
         tListItem["Archive Date"] = dt;
         tListItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```

or

```
fListItem[field.Id] = ((DateTime)fListItem[field.Id]).AddDays(7);
```